# Как сделать добавление товара в корзине?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы при каждом клике на кнопку, число в другом блоке изменялось на единицу(+1)?

```js
$('.add-tovar').click(function() {
  total_items = parseInt($("#tovar")) + 1;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- корзина, вот надо чтобы в ней изменялся span на +1 -->

<div class="bassket">
  <p>
    Товаров:<span id="tovar">0</span> Цена:
    <span id="cena">0</span>
  </p>
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.add-tovar').click(function () {
    $("#tovar").text(parseInt($("#tovar").text()) + 1);
})
```

Comment: Дай бог тебе здоровья

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Бог здоровья даст, а отметить ответ как принятый - стрелка вверх слева - можете только вы.